# Displaying a popover around a UIButton inside UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, selector, uibarbuttonitem, ibaction

`userButtonPressed` gets called with the `UIButton` as parameter, when the `userUIBtn` gets clicked.

However, I would like to **access the `UIBarButtonItem`** instead, in order to display a popover around.

Here is the `generateToolbar()` method, which generates the **user** navigation button.

```
-(void) generateToolbar {

    // Initialize the `ButtonFactory`

    ButtonFactory *buttonFactory = [[ButtonFactory alloc] init];

    // Generate some `UIButton(s)`

    UIButton *userUIBtn = [buttonFactory createButtonWithButtonType:ButtonTypeUser];
    userUIBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,55,20);

    // Add an action to the `UIButton`        

    [userUIBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(userButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Generate an `UIBarButtonItem` with the `UIButton` as basis view

    UIBarButtonItem *userBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:userUIBtn];

    // Add the `UIBarButtonItem` into the right side of the `navigationItem`

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: userBtn, nil];

}
```

Here is the `userButtonPressed()` method, which gets triggered by pressing the **user** button and generates a popover around that button **- It is not being called**.

```
- (IBAction) userButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender {

    // Initialize the `ButtonFactory`
    ButtonFactory *buttonFactory = [[ButtonFactory alloc] init];

    // Generate some `UIButton(s)`
    UIButton *feedbackUIBtn = [buttonFactory createButtonWithButtonType:ButtonTypeFeedback iconVisibility:YES textVisibility:YES capitalization:NO iconSize:20.0 textSize:20.0];
    [feedbackUIBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(feedbackBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    feedbackUIBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,300,50);

    // Create a `UIViewController` and add the `UIButtons` as subviews
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [viewController.view addSubview:feedbackUIBtn];

    // Present the `UIViewController`
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    // Set up the `UIPopoverPresentationController`
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = [viewController popoverPresentationController];
    popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
    popController.barButtonItem = sender;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to edit the action handler in two places, I changed the parameter from `UIBarButtonItem` to `UIButton` and changed `popController.barButtonItem = sender;` to `popController.sourceView = sender;`.

```
- (IBAction) userButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    ...
    popController.sourceView = sender;
    ...
}
```